# Start bash script from bash script as cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm trying to start a bash script(test.sh) from a second bash script that runs as a cronjob(startTest.sh) on Ubuntu 14.04.
Cron is running and both scripts work perfectly if called from command line.

startTest.sh looks like this:

```
#!bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/username/path/to/script

bash /home/username/path/to/script/test.sh
```

test.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch it_works.txt
```

My crontab entry looks like this

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/startTest.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would be good if you add a problem description too..

Comment: What is the problem with this approach? Most probably, you are creating the file in `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is generally not to use relative paths (unless you do an explicit `cd`) in scripts run as cron jobs.

`crond` is probably not running from whatever directory you expect it to.  Depending on what user this cron job runs as, the script either does not have permission to create `it_works.txt` in `crond`'s current working directory, or it is creating the file and you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Also there is a chance that the op forgot to do a `chmod +x` to the scripts.

Comment: @sjsam OP did say it works when run manually, so file permissions are probably not the issue.

Comment: Point noted. :-)  I overlooked that part.